Angular Office-Add in + SSO
I was able to successfully create an add-in with Yeoman and the SSO Option. However that was created using JavaScript. I would like to setup an Angular version. I used the Angular option and yeoman (version 1.9.6) but when I called OfficeRuntime.auth.GetToken I get this error:

I'm a bit confused now on how to get Angular working with SSO.
